# Close every other panel apart from the one being opened using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, accordion

I'm trying to click on a panel and open it's body attached to it. However, I'm opening all the bodies.

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<div id="contractModifyPanel" class="container body-content">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <h2>
            {{ title }}
            <span id="role" style="float: right;">             
                <button id="btnExportRateGridContract" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Export Rate Grid
                </button>
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <h4>{{ contractInstructions }}</h4>

    <div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openBodyPanel()">
        <div class="panel-heading warnOnExit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Contract Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="showBody">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openBodyPanel()">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Firm Fees</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="showBody">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openBodyPanel()">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Product Selection</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="showBody">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openBodyPanel()">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Product Level Fees</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="showBody">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" (click)="openBodyPanel()">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-{{arrowDirection}} chevronIcon"></span>
            <h3 class="panel-title">Footnotes and Exceptions</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" *ngIf="showBody">       
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And my .ts file looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modify-contract',
  templateUrl: './modify-contract.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modify-contract.css']
})

export class ModifyContractComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'Modify Contract';
  contractInstructions: string = 'Complete the following steps to create a 
  contract, specify firm and program fees, and assign Product(s)';

  arrowDirection: string = 'right';

  showBody: boolean;

  openPanel: boolean;
  closedPanels: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showBody = false;
 }

  openBodyPanel() {
    this.showBody = !this.showBody;
    this.arrowDirection = (this.showBody ? 'down': 'right');
  }

  ngOnInit() { }


}
```

Every time I choose to click one panel, all of the bodies underneath the specific div opens up. How would I go about opening an individual panel without creating unique identifiers? In case I end up having to create a 100 panels, I don't want to label 100 unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor that logic into a component (which will also help clear up all that redundant copy & paste HTML), the controller instances will each have their own `showBody` property, independent of the other instances.

In terms of closing other panels automatically, there are multiple options:

You can use a parent component/directive that adds all child components to a list. A click on a panel could be handled by this parent which closes all its other panels and opens the one that was clicked on.

Alternatively you could use some directive with a key value which has some internal dictionary keeping track of all panels with the same key. It could then also manage this logic. You would of course have to define this kind of directive on all panels, with the same key.

Comment: Does it not matter that each of the bodies of the panels will look completely different and not just have different information? I can still reuse the 'parent' component?

Comment: @YashChitneni: You can turn all variable parts into inputs. The `panel-title` element content could be a attribute input and what should end up in the `panel-body` can be inserted via `<ng-content>`. You can nest components as much as you want, whether the parent component still serves any use is up to you to decide.